# How to assign the ArrayBuffer to a varaible in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, arraybuffer

I am creating Variable-Length Arrays with Array Buffers.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val b = ArrayBuffer[Int]() // empty array!
b += (1, 2, 3, 5) // append and output: ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Now I want to assign the variable b to a

```
var a = Array[Int]() // a(0) = 10 // error because a is empty array
a = b.toArray // Array(1, 1, 2)
```

Conversely, if I want to assign the Buffer to a new variable c, there is error.

```
var c = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
c = a.toBuffer // Conversely, convert the array a to an array buffer.
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method apply in class GenericCompanion; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
var c = ArrayBuffer[Int]
```

Answer (score 1):

Type of `c` is inferred as `ArrayBuffer`, while `a.toBuffer` returns `mutable.Buffer` (it's one of the superclasses of `ArrayBuffer`). So the easy fix will be to explicitly set type of the `c` to `mutable.Buffer[Int]`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

var a = Array[Int]()
var c:mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
c = a.toBuffer
```

Also, as a side notice, using mutable state like this is discouraged in Scala. Try to rewrite your code using immutable collections and `val`s.